# ¿Cómo hacer log-in en Tripadvisor con Python?

Tags: python, python-requests

Estoy intentando hacer log-in en tripadvisor, pero no consigo tener un 200, siempre obtengo un 403 de forbidden access:

```
def connect_trip_advisor(url):
    with requests.session() as s:
        payload = {
            'email': creds['usr'],
            'password': creds['pwd'],
        }
        cookie = s.cookies.get_dict()
        t = s.post(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookie, data=payload)
        print t.status_code
```

Comment: Lo primero que te preguntaría es: ¿qué estás intentando hacer? ¿en qué consiste tu proyecto? [TripAdvisor tiene su propia API](https://developer-tripadvisor.com/content-api/) (aunque es para proyectos "grandes"); dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer, quizás deberías plantearte usarla. Luego, no sé si vas a poder entrar simplemente mandando el usuario y contraseña tal y como lo haces, parece que el formulario de login incluye varios campos ocultos y tokens que no estás pasando en tu petición (y que están ahí en parte para evitar que gente haga precisamente lo que estás intentando hacer).

Comment: Lo que intento hacer es entrar al endpoint Messages para obtener todos los mensajes, y los que cumplan una característica en concreta, contestarlos con un mensaje de "Le contactaremos en breve". He visto la API de TripAdvisor y no dan acceso a obtener los mensajes.

Comment: Ahí es donde la segunda parte de mi comentario entra en juego. Si ves la petición de acceso que se hace al servidor de TripAdvisor, es mucho más compleja que simplemente el usuario y contraseña: incluye 2 ids de sesión, contexto del formulario, 2 tokens diferentes...